# Creating scrollView below an ImageView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-scrollview

i have got an activity that has an image at the top of the screen. everything below the Image needs to be scrollable. see picture below:

[image]

I have tries placing the ScrollView Layout below the picture but i keep on getting an error saying "Unexpected end of statement" but the opening tag for ScrollView is correct so i am going crazy!

here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.rkmsolutions.restaurantapp.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sapori_banner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/sapori_logo_cropped"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sapori_banner">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/olivesAppetiserImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/olives512x512"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/oliveAppetiserTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/olivesAppetiserImage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/olivesAppetiserImage"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/olivesAppetizerTitleTxtView"
        android:textColor="#b71c1c"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/oliveAppetisersBodyDescription"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/olivesAppetiserImage"
        android:layout_below="@+id/oliveAppetiserTitle"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/olivesAppetiserImage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/olivesAppetiserImage"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/oliveAppetizerDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/oliveAppetiserPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/oliveAppetisersBodyDescription"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/oliveAppetiserTitle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/oliveAppetisersBodyDescription"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/oliveAppetiserPriceText" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/olivesAppetiserImage"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/bruschetta512x512"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/bruschettaAppetiserTitle"
        android:textColor="#b71c1c"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bruschettaAppetisersBodyDescription"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserTitle"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/bruschettaAppetiserDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bruschettaAppetisersBodyDescription"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bruschettaAppetisersBodyDescription"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bruschettaAppetisersBodyDescription"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/bruschettaAppetiserPriceText"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/vegetarian_bruschetta512x512"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        android:id="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserImage"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserImage"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserImage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserImage"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/veggieBruschettaTitle"
        android:textColor="#b71c1c"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/veggieBruschettaDescription"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserImage"
        android:layout_below="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserTitle"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Toasted bread with grilled vegetarian antipasti" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/veggieBruschettaPrice"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="@string/veggieBruschettaPriceString"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/veggieBruschettaDescription"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/veggieBruschettaDescription"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/veggieBruschettaDescription"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserImage"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/paneAglioImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_below="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserImage"
        android:src="@drawable/garlic_bread_pizza512x512"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/paneAglioTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/paneAglioImage"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/paneAglioImage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/paneAglioImage"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/paneAglioTitleString"
        android:textColor="#b71c1c"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/paneAglioDescription"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/paneAglioDescriptionString"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/paneAglioImage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/paneAglioImage"
        android:layout_below="@+id/paneAglioTitle"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/paneAglioImage"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/paneAglioImage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/paneAglioDescription"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/paneAglioDescription"
        android:text="@string/paneAglioPriceString"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/paneAglioDescription"/>



</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

it will be a simple solution but i just dont know what else to try!
thanks SO!

Comment: Remove your image from scrollview

Comment: put all the content which is below `ImageView` in `ScrollView` so that content which is below `ImageView` will scroll. Qn: is that a `ListView` below your image. If Yes then no need to create `ScrollView` as `ListView` by default will scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your `ImageView` on a `RelativeLayout` with `alignParentTop` attribute. And you should define a container layout for your `ImageView` and `TextViews`.

Key point here ; `ScrollView` can only host one children. So you will add your container layout inside `ScrollView` and you will define `layout_below` attribute to make it below on your banner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.rkmsolutions.restaurantapp.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sapori_banner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/sapori_logo_cropped"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sapori_banner">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/olivesAppetiserImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/olives512x512"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/oliveAppetiserTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/olivesAppetiserImage"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/olivesAppetiserImage"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/olivesAppetizerTitleTxtView"
            android:textColor="#b71c1c"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/oliveAppetisersBodyDescription"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/olivesAppetiserImage"
            android:layout_below="@+id/oliveAppetiserTitle"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/olivesAppetiserImage"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/olivesAppetiserImage"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/oliveAppetizerDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/oliveAppetiserPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/oliveAppetisersBodyDescription"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/oliveAppetiserTitle"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/oliveAppetisersBodyDescription"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/oliveAppetiserPriceText" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/olivesAppetiserImage"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/bruschetta512x512"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/bruschettaAppetiserTitle"
            android:textColor="#b71c1c"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bruschettaAppetisersBodyDescription"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserTitle"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/bruschettaAppetiserDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bruschettaAppetisersBodyDescription"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bruschettaAppetisersBodyDescription"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bruschettaAppetisersBodyDescription"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/bruschettaAppetiserPriceText"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/vegetarian_bruschetta512x512"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserImage"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserImage"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserImage"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/veggieBruschettaTitle"
            android:textColor="#b71c1c"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/veggieBruschettaDescription"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserImage"
            android:layout_below="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserTitle"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Toasted bread with grilled vegetarian antipasti" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/veggieBruschettaPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserImage"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/veggieBruschettaDescription"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/veggieBruschettaDescription"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/veggieBruschettaDescription"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/veggieBruschettaPriceString"
            android:textAlignment="center" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/paneAglioImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserImage"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/garlic_bread_pizza512x512"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/paneAglioTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/paneAglioImage"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/paneAglioImage"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/paneAglioImage"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/paneAglioTitleString"
            android:textColor="#b71c1c"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/paneAglioDescription"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/paneAglioImage"
            android:layout_below="@+id/paneAglioTitle"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/paneAglioImage"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/paneAglioImage"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/paneAglioDescriptionString" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/paneAglioImage"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/paneAglioDescription"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/paneAglioDescription"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/paneAglioDescription"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/paneAglioPriceString"
            android:textAlignment="center" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks mate that did exactly what i was wanting it to do!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.rkmsolutions.restaurantapp.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sapori_banner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/sapori_logo_cropped"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sapori_banner">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/olivesAppetiserImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/olives512x512"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/oliveAppetiserTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/olivesAppetiserImage"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/olivesAppetiserImage"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/olivesAppetizerTitleTxtView"
                android:textColor="#b71c1c"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/oliveAppetisersBodyDescription"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/olivesAppetiserImage"
                android:layout_below="@+id/oliveAppetiserTitle"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/olivesAppetiserImage"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/olivesAppetiserImage"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/oliveAppetizerDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/oliveAppetiserPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/oliveAppetisersBodyDescription"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/oliveAppetiserTitle"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/oliveAppetisersBodyDescription"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/oliveAppetiserPriceText" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/olivesAppetiserImage"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/bruschetta512x512"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/bruschettaAppetiserTitle"
                android:textColor="#b71c1c"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bruschettaAppetisersBodyDescription"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserTitle"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/bruschettaAppetiserDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bruschettaAppetisersBodyDescription"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bruschettaAppetisersBodyDescription"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bruschettaAppetisersBodyDescription"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/bruschettaAppetiserPriceText"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/vegetarian_bruschetta512x512"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserImage"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserImage"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserImage"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/veggieBruschettaTitle"
                android:textColor="#b71c1c"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/veggieBruschettaDescription"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserImage"
                android:layout_below="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserTitle"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bruschettaAppetiserImage"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Toasted bread with grilled vegetarian antipasti" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/veggieBruschettaPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserImage"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/veggieBruschettaDescription"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/veggieBruschettaDescription"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/veggieBruschettaDescription"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/veggieBruschettaPriceString"
                android:textAlignment="center" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/paneAglioImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/veggieBruschettaAppetiserImage"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/garlic_bread_pizza512x512"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/paneAglioTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/paneAglioImage"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/paneAglioImage"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/paneAglioImage"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/paneAglioTitleString"
                android:textColor="#b71c1c"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/paneAglioDescription"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/paneAglioImage"
                android:layout_below="@+id/paneAglioTitle"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/paneAglioImage"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/paneAglioImage"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/paneAglioDescriptionString" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/paneAglioImage"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/paneAglioDescription"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/paneAglioDescription"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/paneAglioDescription"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/paneAglioPriceString"
                android:textAlignment="center" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This will not work , because `ScrollView` can only host one children inside.

Comment: @Robert yep... i tried your solution and i got the same error as Emin

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it will work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <RelativeLayout 
                android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#689F38"
            android:gravity="center"        
                    android:layout_gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/header_msg"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="25sp"/>
        </RelativeLayout> 
        <RelativeLayout 
                android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#689F38"
            android:gravity="center"        
                    android:layout_gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/footer_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/footer_msg"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="25sp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <ScrollView 
            android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header"  
            android:fillViewport="true">      
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/myLayout"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:fillViewport="true">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/bodytext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/body_msg"
                    android:textColor="#F44336"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="25sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

For more check [this](http://www.concretepage.com/android/android-scrollview-with-fixed-header-and-footer-layout-example)